# How to get file length in Go?

Tags: file, go

I looked up  [golang.org/pkg/os/#File](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) , but still have no idea.
Seems there is no way to get file length, did I miss something?

How to get file length in Go?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

`(*os.File).Stat()` returns a `os.FileInfo` value, which in turn has a `Size()` method. So, given a file `f`, the code would be akin to

```
fi, err := f.Stat()
if err != nil {
  // Could not obtain stat, handle error
}

fmt.Printf("The file is %d bytes long", fi.Size())
```

Answer (score 125):

If you don't want to open the file, you can directly call `os.Stat` instead.

```
fi, err := os.Stat("/path/to/file")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
// get the size
size := fi.Size()
```

Answer (score 20):

Slightly more verbose answer:

```
file, err := os.Open( filepath ) 
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fi, err := file.Stat()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println( fi.Size() )
```

Comment: Maybe a `defer file.Close()` before the `Stat()`?

Comment: @Timmmm yes - but since this is a code snippet, we can't assume that `fi` io.Reader is not being passed on elsewhere, so closing it may be presumptuous.

Comment: This is generally the correct way to get the size of a file that you will process soon after checking its size.  You never close the file until you're done with it, avoids TOCTOU issues.

Answer (score 16):

Calling os.Stat as sayed by @shebaw (at least in UNIX OS) is more efficient, cause `stat() is a Unix system call that returns file attributes about an inode`, and is not necessary to deal with open the file.

**NOTE**: *Using other method can lead to* `too many open files`  *in multithread/concurrency application, due to the fact that you open the file for query the stats*

Here the benchmark

```golang
func GetFileSize1(filepath string) (int64, error) {
    fi, err := os.Stat(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    // get the size
    return fi.Size(), nil
}

func GetFileSize2(filepath string) (int64, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return fi.Size(), nil
}
```

```
BenchmarkGetFileSize1-8           704618              1662 ns/op
BenchmarkGetFileSize2-8           199461              5668 ns/op
```

Comment: GetFileSize1() should NEVER be used if you need to protect against TOCTOU issues.  For anyone that does not understand TOCTOU, please google it, they are security problems created by things changing between a time of check and the time of use.