# File Bytes Array Length Go

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I have recently started to learn Go. To start with I decided that I would write some code to open a file and output its contents on the terminal window. So far I have been writing code like this:

```
file, err := os.Open("./blah.txt")

data := make([]byte, 100)

count, err := file.Read(data)
```

To obtain up to 100 bytes from a file. Is there any way to ascertain the byte count on a file, such that you could set the correct (or more sensible) byte array length just using the standard Go library?

I understand you could use a slice with something like `Append()` once the extremities of the array have been reached, but I just wondered whether the file size/length/whatever could be accessed prior to instantiating an array through file metadata or something similar.

Comment: Please don't do this.  There is an answer to your question, but this is just simply a bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you need is a way to [get file size in bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133590/how-to-get-file-length-in-go) to create a slice of the same size:

```
f, err := f.Stat()
// handle error 
// ...
size := f.Size()
```

(see [FileInfo](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) for more)

You can then use this size to initialise a slice.

```
data := make([]byte, size)
```

You can also consider [reading the whole file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514184/how-can-i-read-a-whole-file-into-a-string-variable-in-golang) in one call using [`ioutil.ReadFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile).

Answer (score 10):

While you could certainly get the file's size prior to reading
from it (see the other answer), doing this is usually futile
for a number of reasons:

- A filesystem is an inherently racy medium: any number of processes
  might update a given file simultaneously, and even remove it.

  On a filesystem with POSIX semantics (most commodity OSes
  excluding Windows) the only guarantee a successful opening of a file
  gives you is that it's possible to read data from it,
  and that's basically all. (Well, reading may fail due to the error
  in the underlying media but let's not digress further).
- What would you do if you did the equivalent of a `fstat(2)` call,
  as suggested, and it told you the file contains 42 terabytes of data?

  Would you try to allocate a sufficiently large array to hold its contents?

  Would you implement some custom logic which classifies the file's
  size into several ranges and performs custom processing based on that—like,
  say, slurping files less than N megabytes in length and reading
  bigger files piecemeal?
- What if the file grew bigger (was appended to) after you obtained its size?
- What if you later decide to be a more Unix-way-ready and make it possible
  to read the data from your program's standard input stream—like the `cat`
  program on Unix (or its `type` Windows cousin) does?

  You can't know how much data will be piped through that stream;
  and potentially it might be of indefinite length (consider being piped
  the contents of some busy log file on a continuously running system).

Sure, in some applications you *assume* the contents of files do not
change under you feet; one example is archivers like `zip` or `tar` which
record the file's metadata, including its size, along with the file.
(By the way, `tar` detects a file might have changed while the program
was reading its contents and warns the user in that case).

But what I'm leading you to, is that for a task as simple as yours,
there's little point in doing it the way you've come up with.
Instead, just use a buffer of some "sensible" size and gateway the data
between its source and destination through that buffer.

That is, you allocate the buffer, enter a loop, and on each iteration of
it you try to read as much data as fits in the buffer, process whatever
the `Read` function indicated it was able to read, then handle an
end-of-file condition or an error, if it was indicated.

To round up this small crash course, I'd hint that the standard library
already has [`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io#Copy) which, in your
case, may be called like

```
_, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, f)
```

and will shovel all the contents of `f` to the standard output of your
program until EOF or an error is detected.

Last time I checked, this function used an internal buffer of 32 KiB in size,
but you may always check the source code of your Go installation.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this, very informative.

Comment: An example of the explanation can be found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24563853