# How to implement progress counter when parsing large XML files in Go/Golang with xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)?

Tags: go, xml-parsing, tokenize, large-files

I wrote some code to parse large XML files (>3GB) in go following the example on this website: https://blog.singleton.io/posts/2012-06-19-parsing-huge-xml-files-with-go/

The idea is to create `decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)`, then iterate over the file with `decoder.Token()` and meanwhile inspect all `xml.StartElement`. Whenever the right element is found, it gets decoded with `decoder.DecodeElement()`.

That works all very well.

What I like to have now is a method to show progress to the user. Something like "x percent of file processed".

I know how to get the file size of the XML: [How to get file length in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133590/how-to-get-file-length-in-go)

But how can I get the actual (or relative) position of `decoder.Token()`?

Comment: `xml.Decoder` just wraps an `io.Reader`. You can always put your own reader in between that counts the bytes as they go by.

Comment: You might also find this useful (never used it myself but it looks relevant to your needs): https://github.com/mitchellh/ioprogress

Comment: Thank you very much, by now I created a version with ioprogress and after that I found [github.com/machinebox/progress](https://github.com/machinebox/progress) which is a bit more versatile and even offers the remaining time plus triggering via channel. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xml.Decoder` has method `InputOffset`, that return current position. Do you need something else ?

Comment: This is the easy answer. How could I miss that.